# running junit from command line with jar file

Tags: java, command-line, junit

I have two java file, Point.java and PointTest.java. The work fine in eclipse but I'm trying to compile them through commandline

I downloaded the junit 4.8.2 jar file into the same directory as the .java files

I am currently trying this command to compile them but im getting errors

```
javac -cp junit-4.8.2.jar:. Point.java PointTest.java
```

I have tried the command with -cp as well. The first error is

```
 package org.junit does not exist
```

What am I doing wrong here? If I extract the jar file in the directory, then I am able to compile the java files correctly.

In case it helps, the first few import declarations in the test file are

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
```

Comment: Are you using Windows? If so, classpath components need to be separated with a semicolon rather than a colon.

Comment: I am getting the same problem! Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Could you verify if the name of the junit jar is correct. The default name is junit-4.8.2.jar and not junit.4.8.2.jar

Comment: The name is correct. I misspelled it on the question. I even tried renaming it to junit.jar just in case and it still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Compile with the `-verbose` flag so you can see what the compiler is doing. It will print out the classpath.

Comment: it does show that "[search path for source files: junit-4.8.2.jar]". And for class files, it gives me the entire classpath which includes the junit-4.8.2.jar appended to the end. 

After the class path, it give me

[loading java\lang\Object.class(java\lang:Object.class)]
PointTest.java:1: package org.junit does not exist

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking at the examples in the `javac` page, particularly [Separating Source Files and Class Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#separating). Splitting out source, class files and libraries is common. See, for example, the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and [Sun Developers Network - Project Conventions](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/code/projectconventions.html). Most IDEs will encourage a similar layout.

Why not do the simple thing and have source files in the same directory as class files? For one thing, if you delete or rename a class, but forget to delete the class file, you can have source code that references the old class. There are a few other gotchas that most of us don't remember because no one puts classes and source files in the same directory.

If you are just experimenting with Java and JUnit I strongly recommend an IDE like Eclipse. For automated builds you might want to consider looking into Ant, Maven or Ivy, but for getting started an IDE has a smaller learning curve with a lot of extra benefits (code completion, debugging, a UI for reviewing JUnit test failures...).